# Оформление длинной фразы в диалоге

Tags: диалог, пунктуация

Следующая ситуация: между персонажами книги происходит диалог. Затем один из них начинает рассказывать длинную историю. Естественно, она не может идти сплошным абзацем, но как её пунктуационно оформить? Смущает то, что если просто продолжить писать с новой строки, то новый абзац можно спутать с речью от автора (различие по контексту считаю недостаточным критерием для разграничения).

Есть два варианта, которые приходят в голову:

а) текст, заключённый в кавычки;
б) косвенная речь, вроде: «сказав это, он продолжил, упомянув, что»… ну и т.п. по такому же принципу.

Однако интересует именно пунктуационное оформление подобного диалога.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Цитирую правило:

Если передается длинный рассказ со многими абзацами, то тире ставится только перед первым абзацем (ни перед промежуточными абзацами, ни перед последним тире не ставится). Например:

/ -- Это было давно... - начал свой рассказ Петров.

/ К нам в город приехал...

/ (Продолжает рассказ) и т. д.

/ Вот что я хотел вам рассказать, - закончил Петров.

Косыми чертами я отметила абзацные отступы - они тут почему-то не выставляются.

Речь одного и того же лица не может оформляться в одном диалоге то с абзаца, то в подбор (то есть с кавычками). Такое сочетание возможно, если рассказчик в диалоге пересказывает диалог других лиц, тогда это позволяет выделить диалог в диалоге.

В вашем случае надо как-то намекнуть на конец рассказа.